# Return text entered in textbox

Tags: android

I'm trying to work through the ["Start Another Activity"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) tutorial but, having worked through the whole thing (twice), the app still refuses to return the text entered in the textbox - it always returns "Hello World".

I've tried to figure it out, and suspect it might be something to do with the `fragment_display_message.xml`, in which there is an `EditText` calling the Hello World string. But really I have no idea.

Any help would be appreciated. Here's the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.knargle.streetiteatit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.knargle.streetiteatit.MESSAGE";

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new     PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.knargle.streetiteatit.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**DisplayMessageActivity.java**

```
package com.knargle.streetiteatit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new     PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

**fragment_display_message.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.knargle.streetiteatit.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DisplayMessageActivity.java` file, you are calling `setContentView` twice which it-self is overwriting the first line of code. Currently your code looks like this:

```
setContentView(textView);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message); // Delete this line. As this line of code appears in your java file, it is overwriting the 'text' you entered with the default 'hello world' message
```

It should be just like this:

```
setContentView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setContentView` is being called twice in `DisplayMessageActivity`. Remove the second one:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `DisplayMessageActivity`:

```
// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

You call `setContentView` twice, which just overwrites what was already there.  Remove the second `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from `DisplayMessageActivity` :

```
// Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
```

You were attempting to set the message in a new text view which is not part of your layout file. And then setting that text View as the ContentView of your layout. That seems like a convoluted approach. Instead try the following :

After the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);` line, add these lines :

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
editText.setText(message);
```

This way, you use the existing Edit text element in your layout file to show the message. Your original code never replaced HelloWorld in this element. That is why it always shows you HelloWorld instead of your message.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the answers from both Andrew and Rajesh. But the fact that you have defined a layout fragment_display_message and I am sure you want to use it. In that case, all you need to do is get rid of the code to dynamically add the TextView and the correspodning setContentView and leave the second setContentView that uses your layout. Once done, you get the reference to your EditText and set it's text to what was sent in the Intent.